# Parity account in OS windows 10 dissapeared

Tags: parity, parity-wallet

would my lost wallet parity key still be in the location: : $home\AppData\Roaming\Parity\Ethereum\keys\ethereum    even after I have uninstallled and then reinstalled Parity? If so will this allow me restore my lost Parity wallet?  thanx a million for your help!

my twitter is @sduncan621. and I have messenger so my Facebook is https://www.facebook.com/JuliusStevenDuncan …  .need help folks! I still  have my 12 word phrase and parity  password but parity wallet dissapeared and using the "restore procedure" and my 12 word restore phrase only flashes the correct  previous parity wallet address but not the account itself with token content...yesterday I even reinstalled parity using win-installer exe. from parity.io and resynched but still no wallet..can someone please help me? thanx a million!

Comment: What is the result of your windows search for 'keystore'?

Comment: I went into  app data - roaming - parity - ethereum - keys - ethereum and found a bunch of keys starting with UTC which I was unable to open and am not sure how to use them - there was one that although was recently modified still had an older date  prior to when I recently uninstalled  the old version of parity and reinstalled a newer version of parity hoping that would bring my account back...am I suppose to try those keys somewhere to get back my lost account? thanx